# Malaysian going to India tour for second time with same visa - multiple entry

Tags: visas, india, repeat-visits, malaysian-citizens

I am Malaysian planning to visit India.  My visa is valid till 1-1-2020.  Earlier I went in January.  Can I go a second time before the visa expires?

Comment: Visa is multiple entry, which is still valid, right? What is the problem?

Comment: Technically they're asking about multiple entry, not whether they have one.

Comment: What's the type of visa you have?

Answer (score 1):

If visa is multiple entry and is still valid, it means that the visa can be used again to enter India.